# Sketching the joint PMF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Question: The joint PMF of X and Y is $p(x,y)=\frac{1}{6}$ where x and y are non-negative integers satisfying $x+y \le 6$. Sketech the support of X and Y.

I am wondering there can be $(0,0),(0,1)$... all the way to $(6,0),(0,6)$. So there are 28 points for the sample space.

When I sketch, I found 28 points, should I label individual as $\frac{1}{28}$ or $\frac{1}{6}$?

Comment: @ironX Where is $(0,0)$? $(0,1)$? $(1,0)$? And so on.

Comment: nevermind I misread the question as $x + y = 6$. Sorry

Comment: Can you upload the exercise?

Comment: Very mysterious this exercise ...

Comment: @callculus yeah that's why I post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have rightly pointed out, there are $28$ possible pairs for $(x,y)$. Thus, the pdf is not a valid one. Perhaps, it could be $p(x)=p(y)=1/6$ for non-negative integers $x,y\leq 6$. In that case, $p(x,y|x+y\leq 6)=1/28$.

Comment: Yeah, I think the PDF is not a valid one